# How to compare unique element in 2 arrays

Tags: perl

I have 2 lists of array and I want to find it out if any of the word matches, get the both the values.

```
For examples 
array1        array2
int1<->int2   int9<->int1 --->Matched as Int1 is common. Get both the values(e.g int1<->int21,int9<-
int3<->int4   int10<->int11 ->> not matched
int5<->int6   int13<->int14-->> no matched
int7<->int8   int8<->int15 -- Macthed int8 Get $var1=int7<->int8,$var2=int8<->int15
```

hope it make sense.Please let me know incase of any doubts.

Comment: You say `int7<->int8` and `int8<->int15` match on `int5`; do you mean `int8`?

Comment: oh yess I am really sorry for that .. you ar correct it should be int8. Thanks

Comment: You have to show what you've tried, else this question will be put on hold.

Comment: Zaid Thanks for the response I was thinking to split connection1 in my ($first, $second) = split /<\->/, @array1; and then grep my $matched = grep $_ eq $first, @array2; but seems compliated so i though to compare both the arrays directly so want to check on this site.Can this be possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you want, but perhaps this:

```
my @a = qw(int1<->int2 int3<->int4 int7<->int8);
my @b = qw(int9<->int1 int10<->int11 int8<->int15);

for my $i (0..$#a) {
  my ($w1, $w2) = ($a[$i] =~ /([^<]+)<->(.+)/);
  if (index($b[$i],$w1)!=-1 || index($b[$i],$w2)!=-1) {
    print "match: $a[$i], $b[$i]\n";
  }
}
```

Explanation:
There are two (parallel) arrays, `a` and `b`, in which coinciding elements are to be compared. They are compared by extracting two substrings of the `a` element. These are each tested to see if either is a substring of the `b` element. If either is a substring, it's considered a match. (`index` returns the index of substring or -1 if substring is not present.)

Comment: Thanks ooga , But could you please explain what this code is doing may be our understanding doesn't match.

Comment: It's comparing the first element of both arrays then the second element and so on. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: What I understood from you code it's spliting array1 1st value to w1 and w2 ..this is correct and after that it is comparing with index($b[$i].$w1) ..Where this b[$i] came from ... I am not expert .. :) in short we need to compare array1 int1 with array 2 1st element <-> 2nd element if any of that macthes .. print it. I think your code is correct but not able to get the flow

Comment: There are two (parallel) arrays, `a` and `b`, in which coinciding elements are to be compared. They are compared by extracting two substrings of the `a` element. These are each tested to see if either is a substring of the `b` element. If either is a substring, it's considered a match. (`index` returns the index of substring or `-1` if substring is not present.)

Comment: perhaps this should be part of your answer, that would make your answer very good opposed to just correct. @ooga

Comment: ooga's answer as one-liner: `perl -E '@a=qw/int1<->int2 int3<->int4 int7<->int8/; @b=qw/int9<->int1 int10<->int11 int8<->int15/; for $i(0..$#a){($w1, $w2) = ($a[$i] =~ /([^<]+)<->(.+)/); say "$a[$i] $b[$i] match" if (index($b[$i],$w1)!=-1||index($b[$i],$w2)!=-1);}'`

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more perlish solution that translates one of your keys into a list regex that is used to compare.  Therefore captures the key that matches:

```
my @a = qw(int1<->int2 int3<->int4 int7<->int8);
my @b = qw(int9<->int1 int10<->int11 int8<->int15);

for my $i (0..$#a) {
    my $list_re = join '|', map quotemeta, split '<->', $a[$i];
    if ($b[$i] =~ /\b($list_re)\b/) {
        print "match $1: $a[$i], $b[$i]\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly more laborious approach than the one taken by ooga. I'm speaking a less fluent version of **Perl**  here :-)

The script separates the data into arrays and creates two patterns by matching and holding with subpatterns `=~ /()...()/` and storing these as variables (pretty much the same as ooga's approach). Then I loop through one of the arrays matching each element against elements of the other array using a second regex. With more complex strings, unevenly distributed data, or a larger set data I'm not sure the `foreach` `if..elsif` logic mightn't miss something. However as a quick test I compared the script below against ooga's work and they give the same output ;-)

A smartmatch (`~~`), [`match::simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/match%3a%3asimple) or [`match::smart`](https://metacpan.org/pod/match%3a%3asmart) might work in newer versions of **Perl**.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my (@col1, @col2);

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp; my @data =  split/ / ;
  push @col1, $data[0];
  push @col2, $data[1];
}

foreach my $i (0 .. $#col1 ) {
  my ($patt1, $patt2) = ( $col1[$i] =~ /([^<]+)<->(.+)/ );
  if ($col2[$i] =~ $patt1 ) { 
    print "$col1[$i] matches $col2[$i]  \n";
  }
  elsif ($col2[$i] =~ $patt2 ) {
    print "$col1[$i] matches $col2[$i]  \n";
  }
}

__DATA__
int1<->int2 int9<->int1
int3<->int4 int10<->int11
int5<->int6 int13<->int14
int7<->int8 int8<->int15
```

I have to say I really do prefer ooga's clean `index` based approach.  Vote me up if my script works (*i.e.* test it) and you like traditional **Perl** regex-iness.

Cheers and happy `perl`-ing.